# Time scaling in non-homogenous second-order ODE

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

We have a second-order ODE of the form
$$
\tau^2 \ddot{x}(t) = \phi(t/\tau) u(\phi),
$$
where $\phi(t/\tau)$ and $u(\phi)$ can be anything. If I scale $\tau$ with $\mu$ (i.e. $\tau_2 = \mu \tau_1$), I observe the following
$$
x_2 (t/\mu) = x_1(t)\\
\mu \dot x_2 (t/\mu) = \dot x_1(t).
$$
**Question 1** How can I explain this behavior mathematically?

**Question 2** So far, whatever functions I chose for $\phi(t/\tau)$ and $u(\phi)$, the above equations hold. Do these functions need to have some sort of criteria?

Comment: This does not make sense. By the chain rule you would have to divide by $\mu$, not multiply with it.

Comment: True that. $\dot x_2$ is already divided by $\mu$. That is why we multiply it with $\mu$ to get it equal to $\dot x_1$.

Comment: Nothing much makes sense. Where is $\dot x_2$ already multiplied with $\mu$, better with $\mu^2$? Is $\phi$ a function or a variable or a constant? Is the original problem not just a simple quadrature? Is there a part of the equation or system missing?

Comment: Dear Dr. Lehmann,

As I said this is what I observe and have no explanation for it. The amplitude of $\dot x_2(t/\mu) is 1/\mu \dot x_1(t)$. $\phi(t/\tau)$ is an arbitrary function like sin, cos, exp or any other linear or nonlinear functions. This is the reduced version of dynamical movement primitives (DMPs) ODEs which are known to account for temporal (time) scalability (equation 2 and 3).
I have a Simulink model for this system. I am not sure how I can share it here. But you can clearly observe the time scalability, as I wrote in the equation 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that
$$
\tau_i^2\ddot x_i = r\circ d_i , \qquad i\in\lbrace 1,2\rbrace
$$
where $d_i:t\mapsto t/\tau_i$ and $r\circ d_i$ denotes the right-hand side of the proposed differential equations. If $x_1(t) = x_2(\theta)$ with $\theta = t/\mu$ and $\mu = \tau_1/\tau_2$, then by virtue of the chain rule, we have $\dot x_1(t) = \dot x_2(\theta)/\mu$ and $\ddot x_1(t) = \ddot x_2(\theta)/\mu^2$. Therefore,
$$
\tau_1^2 \ddot x_1(t) - r\circ d_1(t) = \tau_2^2 \ddot x_2(\theta) - r\circ d_2(\theta) =0
$$
which explains the similitude between $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(\theta)$. Note that the definition of $\mu$ in OP had to be modified.